# How to handle User Access Control when using MAPI in .NET

Tags: .net, windows-vista, uac, mapi

I've used MAPI to create emails with attachments from my application  and it works very well on XP and Vista (without UAC). Of course, if you have UAC enabled, it just doesn't work (though it gives no errors, and doesn't prompt the user for permission to continue).

I've done a bunch of reading and have found a lot of differing ideas:

- Require Admin privileges for the app
- Require some form of elevated
  privileges for the app
- Create a COM object for the small
  portions of code that require
  elevation
- Get the OS to prompt the users
  asking them if they want to
  continue.

I'm wondering what SO Users would do given that I really only need elevation for one or two functions. I'm looking for the minimal amount of pain here (I don't do COM, but I can P/Invoke with the best of them...), and I'm working in .NET 2.0 (it's a legacy app).

EDIT:
I agree that elevating the whole app isn't a great idea given that only part of it needs the eleveation, but my thought had been that might be easier in the long run than trying to elevate only part of it.

Also, I'd rather stay away from the .NET SMTP solution, since my goal is simply to create a message and with an attachment, but display it to the user so that they can add more text and send it at their leisure...

Answer (score 0):

If you can give up [MAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAPI) in favor of the more general [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP), you can use .NET's [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(VS.80).aspx) class.
Together with the [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(VS.80).aspx) class, you can add [attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(VS.80).aspx) and send messages via any willing [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP) server.

All available in good old .NET 2.0 as managed code - no need for p/invoke or COM.
Examples in the referenced pages.